The astonomer's method of color differencing as applied to proving Einsteinian relativity during a total solar eclipse
I'm looking to see if the astonomers' method of color differencing was ever applied to the stars near the Sun during a total solar eclipse, for example, to demonstrate Einsteinian relativity visually as proof of concept, though perhaps not useful for rigorous measurement. For example, a close-up of stars photographed during the eclipse being filtered blue and an identical image photographed not during an eclipse in which the Sun is blotted out using an opaque circular area held between the camera and the sun, the second image being filtered in yellow, and the two combined.  That would, I think, cause even tiny deflections in the apparent positions of stars to be visually obvious, the effect becoming more pronounced with nearness to the Sun, stars displaying yellow and blue fringes bordering green stars.  Might have been a good way to get the public excited in the era when general relativity was still unproven and unknown by most.

"which the Sun is blotted out using an opaque circular area held between the camera and the sun, " this doesn't work.

Why would it not?

Might need a collimator too?

@user1621287 Use your hand to blot out the Sun. Can you see any stars?

What would make more sense would be to compare your photograph of the stars near the Sun during the eclipse with a photograph of the same field of stars ~ six months later, when it's night.
Of course, to demonstrate GR, you'd have to actually measure the deflection of stars near the Sun (during the eclipse), since there was a non-GR prediction that had half the effect.

My goof - "in which the Sun is blotted out using an opaque circular area held between the camera and the sun" makes no sense, certainly not without collimation.  Can't one make out the stars during the day from the bottom of a well, though such a well wouldn't necessarily point at the portion of sky of interest.  But suppose it's six months later, as Peter suggests.  Surely someone has compared the portion of the starfield of interest with color differencing.  I'd like to see an example.

I gave you all your upvote doggie biscuits.  Won't anyone offer anything more, please?

Like, maybe where I could find two images with and without gravitational lensing, presumably brightness/illumination normalized that are combined with color differencing?  Surely, SOMEONE has done that.
